# How can I fix the cronR automation error on user?

Tags: r, automation, cron

I started using cronR package in R in order to automate some processes in R.

I have an R script stored somewhere on my Mac.When I run it for the first time with a specific id  it works fine.Creates the .log file that contains the automation.

The problem is that if I run it again it reports an error saying that :

```
Can't add this job: a job with id 'id1' already exists
```

my code is the below:

```
library(cronR)

folder = "...path"
cmd = cron_rscript(folder)
cron_add(command = cmd, frequency = 'minutely', 
         id = 'id1', description = 'permonthanalysis')
```

How can I fix this problem ?
And second is there a way automatically the result of this automation process to be a word of excel or pdf file ?

Comment: For your second question "automatically ... excel or pdf", I suggest you look into creating an rmarkdown document and having the cron job knit/render it.

Comment: @r2evans You are right I haven’t bought that.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cron_rm to delete your existing job before you do cron_add with the same job id again